# csv writerow() overwriting

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Why does the user data keeps going to the first line and overwriting the past ones?

```
with open('data_storage.csv', 'r') as read_storage:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(read_storage)

    with open('data_storage.csv', 'w') as write_storage:
        credentials = [username, password]
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(write_storage, fieldnames=credentials, delimiter='\t')
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

I started using the CSV module yesterday so it might be a dumb question, sorry.

Comment: You can't have the same file open in both read and write modes at the same time. As soon as you open a file in write mode, you wipe its contents

Comment: Write the output to a temporary file and then when done, replace the original file with it — you can use `os.replace()` to do the latter.